# Question about private ip address and public ip address

Tags: networking

Let say a company bought a range of ip 172.16.1.0/24 , my question is this range of ip is public or private? and another question why the company not using private ip address to subnet and use NAT to connect to the internet instead of buying range of ip

Comment: You need to buy or rent public addresses. Private addresses you can use at your convenience, but you cannot use them on the Internet.

Comment: From the perspective of IPv4, there is no difference between public and private IP addresses. The only difference between to two is that the ISPs have agreed not to route the arbitrarily defined private IPv4 addresses between them. To IPv4, the are just addresses. IPv6 has eliminated private addressing in favor of ULA, which has a high degree of uniqueness because there are 40 random bits (256 times the entire .theoretical IPv4 address range) in the addressing

Answer (score 3):

Private IPv4 ranges are defined in [RFC1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918). `172.16.0.0/12` is one of the ranges defined as private in that document.

NAT breaks end to end connectivity, so if you require that (for example because you're hosting services), you need to have publicly routed IPv4 addresses.